# How to conditionally format (color, etc) cells being counted by COUNTIF function in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, countif

I have a COUNTIF statement that is working fine. But I would like to the conditionally format the cells that are being counted so I can identify them more easily. So it is counting the number of cells in a long list that fall into one of 7 categories. I would like the the cells being "counted" in each category to be formatted such that they become a unique color or whatever. Is this possible?

Comment: Is it possible? Most likely yes. But to satisfactorily answer the question, you should [edit] your question with sample data, the expected result, and what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Select the range that you want to apply the conditional formatting on.

`Conditional Formatting` -> `New Rule` -> `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`

From there type in the following formula:
 `=ISFORMULA(RANGE)`

*Replace `RANGE` with the first value in the column you are formatting*

Edit formatting to your liking.